# Modify Xml using XDocument/XPath C#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml

I am wondering about XDocument possibilities in relation to xml and how it can modify xml. Let's assume I have next xml:

```
    <client>
        <firstName>Ian</firstName>
        <firstName>Charles</firstName>
        <city>LosAngeles</city>
        <state>California</state>
    </client>
```

Can I leave there only one "firstname" node (which is at the very top) by using XDocument or XPath operations? I want to do something like .Distinct() operation does in LINQ. I want to make my resulting xml look like this:

```
   <client>
       <firstName>Ian</firstName>
       <city>LosAngeles</city>
       <state>California</state>
   </client>
```

Comment: Would this be of any use? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987470/xpath-to-get-unique-element-names

Comment: Is the first firstname tag always the one you want?

Comment: Yes, the firstname tag is always the one I want.

Answer (score 2):

Just search for all `firstName` elements within a `client` and remove all but the first.  You can find all of the `firstName` elements to remove using this xpath query:

```
//client/firstName[position() > 1]
```

So just remove them.

```
doc.XPathSelectElements("//client/firstName[position() > 1]").Remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach(XElement client in doc.Descendants("client"))
            {
                List<XElement> firstNames = client.Elements("firstName").ToList();
                XElement newFirstName = new XElement(firstNames.FirstOrDefault());
                firstNames.Remove();
                client.AddFirst(newFirstName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```